# Can't bind to color since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular

### Error

```
Can't bind to color since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

### Code

```
@Component({
    selector: "nav-next",
    template: `
    <div class="nav-next-directive">
        <button [color]="color" class="primary" [
        </button>
    </div>`
})
```

### Expected Behaviour

This child directive enabled us in Angular2-RC4 to set colors dynamically from the parent component. Angular2-Final says this is no good. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your directive implementation here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the debut of `ngModule`, you have to include your `Directive` into the `ngModule declarations` array before using it:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ColorDirective ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And make sure your `Directive` `selector` is of property type too:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[color]"
})
```

Here is the working example, if you change either one of the two things above, you'll get that error: http://plnkr.co/edit/ymUTyuMo9FsSORd9XI2H?p=preview

Comment: All was good, turns out that color property was a mistake during a global search and replace.

Answer (score 8):

For any one else having this issue and the other answer didn't work, this worked for me.

Changing [color] to [style.color]

```
 <div class="nav-next-directive">
    <button [style.color]="color" class="primary" [
    </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I primarily used @Ruan suggestion, but it seems didn't work well. Although I've got rid of that annoying error messages, this also messed up with the button background color.

Solution for me was adding `MatButtonModule` to TestBed imports which were using that component.